# iPhone automation - web testing

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, appium, appium-ios

Every time I launch a script, instead of automating the login page, driver takes session from previous script. I am running the script on iPhone simulator. I am also resetting the device. Please refer the above code for more info,

```
ServerArguments serverArguments = new ServerArguments();
serverArguments.setArgument("--address", "127.0.0.1");
serverArguments.setArgument("--no-reset", false);
serverArguments.setArgument("--command-timeout", 2400);
serverArguments.setArgument("--local-timezone", true);
serverArguments.setArgument("--full-reset", true);
this.appiumServer = new AppiumServer(new File("/usr/local/bin/node"), new File("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js"),serverArguments);
            this.appiumServer.startServer();
```

I am using Genium framework for starting/stopping appium server.

I am setting the above capabilities in DesiredCapabilities class,

```
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
capabilities.setCapability("udid", udid);
capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Safari");
if (!platformVersion.equals("")) {
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", platformVersion);
}
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", deviceName);
capabilities.setCapability("autoWebview", true);
capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 120);
```